# Why do array[n] and array[x] where x=n return different values?

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging

Does anyone know what may cause the read-back values of array[n] and array[x] (x=n) different from each other?

**EDIT**: Following is a compilable code to illustrate the problem I encountered. If you run the following code, you won't see any problem. I am just using it to describe the problem I saw in my original program which is a simulator with 100+ classes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MySimulatorImplementationBy100Classes;

class MySimulator {
public:
    enum SigList {
        SIG0,
        SIG1,
        SIG2,
        // ...
        SIG18=18,
        SIG19=19,
        SIG70=70,
        SIG80=80
    };

    void run() {}
private:
    MySimulatorImplementationBy100Classes *impl_;
};

int main() {
    MySimulator sim;
    // set up the simulation 

    sim.run();

    enum SigAnalysis {
        ANALYSIS0,
        ANALYSIS1,
        ANALYSIS2,
        ANALYSIS3,
        ANALYSIS4,
        ANALYSIS5,
        ANALYSIS6,
        NUM_ANALYSIS
    };

    const MySimulator::SigList signal_source[NUM_ANALYSIS] = {
        MySimulator::SIG18,
        MySimulator::SIG18,
        MySimulator::SIG18,
        MySimulator::SIG18,
        MySimulator::SIG70,
        MySimulator::SIG80,
        MySimulator::SIG19
    };

    for(int i=0; i<NUM_ANALYSIS; ++i) {
        cout <<signal_source[i]<<"\t" << MySimulator::SIG80 <<"\t" << signal_source[5] << "\t" << i << "\t";
        cout << &signal_source[i]<<"\t" << &signal_source[5]<< "\n";
    }

}
```

In my program, the outputs are

```
18              80      80      0       0xfffe1c90      0xfffe1ca4
18              80      80      1       0xfffe1c94      0xfffe1ca4
18              80      80      2       0xfffe1c98      0xfffe1ca4
18              80      80      3       0xfffe1c9c      0xfffe1ca4
70              80      80      4       0xfffe1ca0      0xfffe1ca4
173068832               80      80      5       0xfffe1ca4      0xfffe1ca4
168047112               80      80      6       0xfffe1ca8      0xfffe1ca4
```

While I expect it to be

```
18              80      80      0       0xfffe1c90      0xfffe1ca4
18              80      80      1       0xfffe1c94      0xfffe1ca4
18              80      80      2       0xfffe1c98      0xfffe1ca4
18              80      80      3       0xfffe1c9c      0xfffe1ca4
70              80      80      4       0xfffe1ca0      0xfffe1ca4
80              80      80      5       0xfffe1ca4      0xfffe1ca4
19              80      80      6       0xfffe1ca8      0xfffe1ca4
```

I don't know why `signal_source[i]` when i=5 returns something different from `signal_source[5]`, while `&signal_source[i]` and `&signal_source[5]` are identical.

Furthermore, if I add some dummy codes somewhere before the `for` loop of  `cout`

```
    sim.run();

    // dummy print
    cout << "dummy\n";

    enum SigAnalysis { //...
```

The results will change:

```
dummy 
172402312               80      80      0       0xfffe1c90      0xfffe1ca4
172446752               80      80      1       0xfffe1c94      0xfffe1ca4
18              80      80      2       0xfffe1c98      0xfffe1ca4
18              80      80      3       0xfffe1c9c      0xfffe1ca4
70              80      80      4       0xfffe1ca0      0xfffe1ca4
80              80      80      5       0xfffe1ca4      0xfffe1ca4
19              80      80      6       0xfffe1ca8      0xfffe1ca4
```

Does anyone have a clue what may go wrong here?

I am using gcc ver 3.4.6. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you put together a compilable example? Is this stripped code? (And on a side note, you might want to use a more recent version of gcc)

Comment: Your code above works fines for me in VS2010 except I had to fill up the missing enums indicated by .... Therefore, please do as GMan suggests to figure out what is happening with your code.

Comment: You may also want to print out i with your results to verify your indexes aren't doing anything strange. Not sure if that will help, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is that something is corrupting `signal_source` (or prehaps `i`).

Post a more complete code sample.

UPDATE:  Here is my test program.  It worked exactly as expected.

```
enum SigList { 
    SIG0, 
    SIG1, 
    SIG2, 
    SIG18 = 18,
    SIG70 = 70,
    SIG80 = 80,
    SIG100 = 100
}; 
const SigList signal_source[7] = { 
    SIG1, 
    SIG1, 
    SIG1, 
    SIG1, 
    SIG18, 
    SIG70, 
    SIG80 
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << signal_source[0] << "\n";   // return 1 (SIG1) 
    cout << signal_source[1] << "\n";   // return 1 (SIG1) 

    for(int i=0; i<7; ++i) 
    { 
        cout << signal_source[i] << "\n"; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to run the program under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).  I've found that these kind of random corruption issues can be caused by passing uninitialized values to system calls.

Here's another idea:  try putting random print statements all over the place and see if that changes where the problem occurs, then it's a sure sign of memory corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps when you reach the for loop, `signal_source` is empty, because you didn't initialize it yet, or because you are in another function?